# Web traffic/activity monitor

Tags: web, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [software to track internet usage on family computer](https://superuser.com/questions/90486/software-to-track-internet-usage-on-family-computer)

Is there a good free monitor that will allow me to monitor my son's internet activity. I'm specifically looking for history of websites visited and time spent on the site. I think that he is visiting sites that his mom would not approve of but is erasing the history etc.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/90486/software-to-track-internet-usage-on-family-computer

Comment: What OS is on the system?

Comment: @DaveM: Windows Vista.